# If value out of expected range give a response

Tags: python, dictionary, time, logic

A program that receives 5 integers and stores them and their cubes in a dictionary. If the number entered is less than 3, raise a user-defined exception NumberTooSmall, and if the number entered is more than 30, then raise a user-defined exception NumberTooBig. Regardless of whether an exception occurs, print the dictionary’s contents at the end.
MY code

```
n1,n2,n3,n4,n5 = int(input()),int(input()),int(input()),int(input()),int(input())
All = sorted([n1,n2,n3,n4,n5])

class NumberTooSmall(Exception):
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.num = args

class NumberTooBig(Exception):
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.num = args

dic = {}
try:
    for i in All:
        if i <3:
            raise NumberTooSmall(i)
        elif i> 30:
            raise NumberTooBig(i)
        else:
            dic[i] = i**3
except NumberTooSmall as numtosmall:
    dic = {**{'NumberTooSmall':numtosmall.num},**dic}        
except NumberTooBig as numtobig:
    dic = {**{'NumberTooBig':numtobig.num},**dic}

keypairs = list(zip(dic.keys(),dic.values()))
  
for i in keypairs:
    if i[0] == 'NumberTooSmall' or i[0] == 'NumberTooBig':
        print('{'+str(i[0]+' ',':',' '+str(i[1])+'}'))
    else:
        print(str(i[0])+' ',':',' '+str(i[1]))
```

Input

```
3
7
9
22
34
```

Expected output

```
{'Number too big': 34}
3  :  27
7  :  343
9  :  729
22  :  10648
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.  If this code isn't doing what you want, then explain what the code **actually does**, and explain what you **expected** it to do.

Comment: what is the problem? Do you get error message? Show it in question (not in comment)Do you get wrong result? Show it in question. Don't expect that we will run code to see problem. Besides it may run correctly on our computers.

Comment: as for me you should run `try/except` inside `for`-loop

Comment: to make it simpler you could assign values directly to variable `n1,n2,n3,n4,n5 ` instead of using `input()` - this way we could test it much faster. You could even put code in function and test it with different values without typing again and again values in `input()`. And later you can add code which gets value from `input()` and also run function. Or you could read data from file and also run function.

Comment: if an exception is raised, then the code is halted. this is the purpose of an exception.

Answer (score 1):

This was a good attempt. I basically made the following three improvements.

1. move `try`-`except` block inside the loop.
2. cleaned up the `dic[]` inside the `except`
3. tidy up the print statement.

so now the code looks like this:

```py
n1,n2,n3,n4,n5 = 1,5,10,30,50
All = sorted([n1,n2,n3,n4,n5])

class NumberTooSmall(Exception):
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.num = args

class NumberTooBig(Exception):
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.num = args

dic = {}
for i in All:
    try:

        if i <3:
            raise NumberTooSmall(i)
        elif i> 30:
            raise NumberTooBig(i)
        else:
            dic[i] = i**3
    except NumberTooSmall as numtosmall:
        dic[i] = 'NumberTooSmall'        
    except NumberTooBig as numtobig:
        dic[i] = 'NumberTooBig'

keypairs = list(zip(dic.keys(),dic.values()))


for i,v in keypairs:
    print(f'{i} : {v}')
```

and the result is this:

```
1 : NumberTooSmall
5 : 125
10 : 1000
30 : 27000
50 : NumberTooBig
```

Comment: simpler `for k,v in dic.items(): ...` without `keypairs`. `keypairs` could be useful if you would have to sort by keys - to make sure it will display in correct order.

Comment: @furas,  yes,  you are totally correct there. i was just trying to continue the existing code. in fact, could have even completed with `print(dic)`. So thanks for the comment.